# Server side validation idea, searching for a better way to validate server side form submission

Tags: php, database, laravel-4, server-side

I want to create a strong server side validation for my website. Specially to prevent a single user commenting on a post multiple time. Or prevent submitting single data to the database more than one time.
For this I thought It would be nicer if a single user to be blocked for 10 seconds to interact with the database, after his last interaction.

1> Is there any other way to prevent this error or spam protection from server side ?

2> Will it be ok to store the time of post and check the next interaction availability by matching current time and that time on database or there is another way ?

Thank you in advance for helping me in this tiny research !

Answer (score 0):

Use Eloquent events and return false if the user should be stopped.

```
Comment::creating(function()
{
   // Check if the user has posted another comment within the last 10 seconds
   // e.g.:
   if (Comment::where('user_id', $userId)->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subSeconds(10))->count()) return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Specially to prevent a single user commenting on a post multiple time. Or prevent submitting single data to the database more than one time

This is trivial to enforce at the database tier (assuming you're using a relational database). You could construct the logic to control this in PHP - but it is complex and unnecessary.

> or spam protection from server side ?

Yes, of course you can validate data server-side - but you'll need to be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve. There are lots of tools like Spamassassin and Akismet which are very sophisticated, well tested and easy to integrate in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a strong server side validation for my website.
>   Specially to prevent a single user commenting on a post multiple time.

The general term for that on the database side is *constraint*. If you want to limit each user to one comment per post, you'd use either a primary key constraint or a unique constraint. For example, if you had a table named "comments", that table would likely contain

- a foreign key constraint to the table of posts (because a comment is about a particular post) and
- a foreign key constraint to the table of users (because each comment comes from a particular user).

  ```
  Table: comments
  post_id    user_id
  --
  1          1
  1          2
  1          3
  2          7
  ```

Enforce that constraint with either `primary key (post_id, user_id)` or with `unique (post_id, user_id)`.

> Or prevent submitting single data to the database more than one time.

I can imagine a few different meanings for that requirement. You might want to edit your question, and add some more details.

> For this I thought It would be nicer if a single user to be blocked for 10 seconds to interact with the database, after his last interaction.

These two "requirements" mean radically different things.

- I want to limit the user to one comment per post, and *only* one comment per post.
- I want to limit the user to one comment per post every 10 seconds. So if the user is patient, I want to let them enter 137 comments per post.

This can be done with triggers in the back end, or with application code in the front end. SQL database management systems don't yet generally support declarative constraints among rows or among tables.